# How to determine if the user has enough permissions to Share ContentDocument to sObject

Tags: contentdocument, contentdocumentlink, userrecordaccess

I have a situation that seems to be consistent with the top comments here: https://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=087300000006n4GAAQ

Specifically, i have a Content Workspace aka Content Library, and a user added to it as a Collaborator (directly, not via group) with `Read` access.

If the user opens a record (e.g. `Account`) and tries to use `Add Files` button in LEX and selects that file in the Library, sharing fails with the error:

> Can't add 1 file to Account.

I can see in Chrome that Aura action from the API said:

```
{
            "id": "9304;a",
            "state": "SUCCESS",
            "returnValue": {
                "SomeId": {
                    "docId": "DocId here",
                    "recordId": "record Id Here",
                    "shareSuccess": false,
                    "shareExists": false,
                    "canUserEditFile": false
                }
            },
            "error": []
        }
```

So LEX can somehow determine that the user `canUserEditFile`.

**How can i do the same in Apex?**

My goal is to automatically create `ContentDocumentLink` records via a trigger, and so I need to determine whether that is possible.

When I run the following query:

```
SELECT RecordId,MaxAccessLevel FROM UserRecordAccess WHERE UserId = 'User' AND RecordId = 'record'
```

I get the access level as `All` for the same file that is throwing that error